# How do I delete elements with certain attributes with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

With javascript, I am trying to remove and delete elements in the ion-list (or each of the individual ion-item elements) that have this CSS property

```
transform: translate3d(-9999px, -9999px, 0px);
```

but I'm not able to do so. Currently, with the javascript below, all elements get deleted. I'd also like to remove any references to these elements. The HTML here is dynamically generated. In the HTML example below, an item with the CSS property I'm referring to are towards the bottom.

Any advice on how to do this?

Javascript:

```
function removeElementsByClass(className){
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    Array.from(elements).forEach(el => {
        el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
    });
    console.log(elements);
}

removeElementsByClass('item');
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="collection-repeat-container" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">

  <ion-item collection-repeat="item in locations" style="padding: 0px 0px 15px; border: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); height: 550px; width: 451px;" class="item">



    <!-- START OF IMAGE -->
    <div class="item item-image">
      <a on-tap="getMap($index)" class="disable-user-behavior">
        <img src="http://41.media.tumblr.com/c1f8c181025553297b6939e152b9952e/tumblr_mudb5hymz41r1thfzo6_1280.jpg" class="image" style="height: 450px;">
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- END OF IMAGE -->

    <div class="item item-text-wrap" style="border-color:white; padding-bottom:25px;">
      <label class="positive">
        <i class="ion-information-circled positive"></i>
      </label>

        <label style="font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif" class="ng-binding">&nbsp;A beautiful place because of the sound the wind makes as it blows through the thick bamboo grove.</label>

    </div>


  </ion-item>

  <ion-item collection-repeat="item in locations" style="padding: 0px 0px 15px; border: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 549px, 0px); height: 550px; width: 451px;" class="item">



    <!-- START OF IMAGE -->
    <div class="item item-image">
      <a on-tap="getMap($index)" class="disable-user-behavior">
        <img src="http://209.205.207.20/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/31.jpg" class="image" style="height: 450px;">
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- END OF IMAGE -->

    <div class="item item-text-wrap" style="border-color:white; padding-bottom:25px;">
      <label class="positive">
        <i class="ion-information-circled positive"></i>
      </label>

        <label style="font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif" class="ng-binding">&nbsp;The dense growth of conifers in the forest blocks out most of the light inside the forest.</label>

    </div>


  </ion-item>

  <ion-item collection-repeat="item in locations" style="padding: 0px 0px 15px; border: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 1098px, 0px); height: 550px; width: 451px;" class="item">



    <!-- START OF IMAGE -->
    <div class="item item-image">
      <a on-tap="getMap($index)" class="disable-user-behavior">
        <img src="http://209.205.207.20/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/41.jpg" class="image" style="height: 450px;">
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- END OF IMAGE -->

    <div class="item item-text-wrap" style="border-color:white; padding-bottom:25px;">
      <label class="positive">
        <i class="ion-information-circled positive"></i>
      </label>

        <label style="font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif" class="ng-binding">&nbsp;Vast farmlands get covered in golden, yellow rapeseed flowers stretching as far as the eyes can see.</label>

    </div>


  </ion-item>

  <ion-item collection-repeat="item in locations" style="padding: 0px 0px 15px; border: 0px; transform: translate3d(-9999px, -9999px, 0px); height: 0px; width: 0px;" class="item">



    <!-- START OF IMAGE -->
    <div class="item item-image">
      <a on-tap="getMap($index)" class="disable-user-behavior">
        <img src="{{item.imageLink}}" class="image" style="height: {{windowWidth}}px;">
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- END OF IMAGE -->

    <div class="item item-text-wrap" style="border-color:white; padding-bottom:25px;">
      <label class="positive">
        <i class="ion-information-circled positive"></i>
      </label>

        <label style="font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif" class="ng-binding">&nbsp;{{item.Fact}}</label>

    </div>


  </ion-item></div>


</div></ion-list>
```

Comment: What does not work exactly?Any errors in the console?

Comment: Currently all the elements get deleted. I'm only trying to delete elements with transform: translate3d(-9999px, -9999px, 0px).

Comment: `transform` is not an attribute, it is CSS property.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the question to say that it is a CSS property.

Comment: You're clearly not understanding. MinusFour told you what you need to know. You should look up elements by the style attribute and inspect their CSS looking for `transform`. That's not what you're doing.

Comment: well you would need to select by classname, than loop through and look at the style attribute and see if it has the transform. OR just give them all a class name that is unique to start.

Comment: I think I understand what I need to do, but I'm not sure how to do it...do you have a code snippet I can see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's always on the style attribute then you can modify your loop to this:

```
Array.from(elements).forEach(el => {
    if(el.style.transform === 'translate3d(-9999px, -9999px, 0px)'){
       el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
    }
});
```

If it's part of CSS stylesheet, things get tricker.